# Add lines between nodes in tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

In my work I need to recreate the following image in LaTeX

[image]

Here is what I have so far

[image]

I am not looking for a perfect recreation of the tree above as I find it quite ugly. However, I do need to recreate it's main features.

- How do I connect L1 and R1 in the tree?
- Is there any way to get the text to be in the middle of the line (I know tikz has some mid command to place text in the middle of a sigment, but not sure how to get it working with tikz)
- How can I get the name and wc to point to the side?

Any help in fixing 1 or more of the bullet poitns above is much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [S1
  [left-bank
  [L1
     [boat
       [$1$]
       ]
     [wolf
       [$1$]
       ]
     [goat
       [$1$]
       ]
     [cabbage
       [$1$]
       ]
  ]
       ]
    [right-bank
      [R1
        [boat
          [$0$]
        ]
        [wolf
          [$0$]
        ]
        [goat
          [$0$]
        ]
        [cabbage
          [$0$]
        ]
  ]
      ]
     [desired
       [D1
       [right-bank
       [DR1
       [boat
       [$1$]
       ]
       [wolf
       [$1$]
       ]
       [goat
       [$1$]
       ]
       [cabbage
       [$1$]
       ]
       ]
       ]
       ]
     ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess that the main conceptual mistake you are making is that you mix up edge labels and nodes. According to how I read your screen shot, e.g. `goat` should be an edge label, not a node. That is, e.g. ` [R1
        [boat
          [$0$]` should become ` [R1
        [$0$,edge label={node[midway]{goat}}]` or something of that sort. Once that is done, the rest is just an adjustment of a few styles and parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, Zarko has also spelled out my comment. Anyway, this version also answers your question how to draw additional lines (arrows) between `L1` and `R1`. I stress that I did not even look at Zarko's code, let alone copied from there. Nor did I down- or upvote his post.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[linguistics,edges]{forest}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadings,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{con/.style={draw=yellow!60!black,line width=2.5pt,-latex},
lbl/.style={pos=0.5,font=\sffamily}}
\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=0.5cm,l sep=1.2cm,
where n children=0{}{top color=yellow!70!white,bottom color=yellow!80!black,
ellipse,draw=yellow!60!black,thick},
edge path={
      \noexpand\path [con, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u)  -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },}
  [S1,alias=S1
    [L1,edge label={node[lbl]{\contour{white}{left-bank}}},alias=L1
       [$1$,edge label={node[lbl,xshift=-2mm]{\contour{white}{boat}}}]
       [$1$,edge label={node[lbl,yshift=2mm]{\contour{white}{wolf}}}]
       [$1$,edge label={node[lbl,yshift=-2mm]{\contour{white}{goat}}}]
       [$1$,edge label={node[lbl,xshift=2mm]{\contour{white}{cabbage}}}]
    ]
    [R1,edge label={node[pos=0.5,font=\sffamily]{\contour{white}{right-bank}}},alias=R1
      [$0$,edge label={node[lbl,xshift=-2mm]{\contour{white}{boat}}}]
      [$0$,edge label={node[lbl,yshift=2mm]{\contour{white}{wolf}}}]
      [$0$,edge label={node[lbl,yshift=-2mm]{\contour{white}{goat}}}]
      [$0$,edge label={node[lbl,xshift=2mm]{\contour{white}{cabbage}}}]
    ]
    [D1,edge label={node[pos=0.5,font=\sffamily]{\contour{white}{desired}}}
      [DR1,edge label={node[pos=0.5,font=\sffamily]{\contour{white}{right-bank}}}
        [$1$,edge label={node[lbl,xshift=-2mm]{\contour{white}{boat}}}]
        [$1$,edge label={node[lbl,yshift=2mm]{\contour{white}{wolf}}}]
        [$1$,edge label={node[lbl,yshift=-2mm]{\contour{white}{goat}}}]
        [$1$,edge label={node[lbl,xshift=2mm]{\contour{white}{cabbage}}}]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\draw[con] (L1.20) -- (R1.160) node[midway,above,lbl]{\contour{white}{other-bank}};  
\draw[con] (R1.-160) -- (L1.-20) node[midway,below,lbl]{\contour{white}{other-bank}}; 
\node[right=2.5cm of S1,lbl] (wcg){wcg}; 
\draw[con] (S1) -- (wcg) node[pos=0.3,above,lbl]{\contour{white}{name}};  
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`forest` is based on `tikz`, so one very convenient way to connect two nodes is to give them names, or `alias`, and then connect them via a simple `\draw` command: `\draw[con] (S1) -- (wcg) node[pos=0.3,above,lbl]{name};`. Here, `con` is a simple-minded attempt to replicate the arrows from your screen shot. (**EDIT**: Made the nodes more funky and also use `contour` to make the edge labels better readable.)